# Problem with list and map in GWT

Tags: list, gwt, dictionary

I have a problem with map and list in GWT. I need to put a map in to a list but GWT does not support ArrayList and HashMap since they are not serialized types.
Exactly I want to create following list with out using ArrayList and HashMap

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

Thank you for new ideas,

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that's the problem? Maybe you don't conform with other serialization requirements? Like a no-arg constructor?

From the [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes):

> A user-defined class is serializable if all of the following apply:
>
> 1. It is assignable to IsSerializable or Serializable, either because it
>      directly implements one of these
>      interfaces or because it derives from
>      a superclass that does
> 2. All non-final, non-transient instance fields are themselves
>      serializable, and
> 3. **As of GWT 1.5, it must have a default (zero argument) constructor
>      (with any access modifier) or no
>      constructor at all.**

Answer (score 3):

You are using Object in your Hashmap.  The Object class is not Serializable.  Replace this with a Serializable type.